# How do I fix my if statement

Tags: ruby, if-statement

I wrote a program where the user inputs a date to find some stock information.

I used a series of `if` statements so the program can look up the type of info they want. There are 10 different types of info the user can look up: "open", "high", "low", "close", "volume", "changed", "percent change", "adjusted closing", "trade value", "trade volume".

The problem is that when information doesn't exist for that type of info, the program doesn't work.

Here is the error that comes up:

```
lookup.rb:75:in `<main>': undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

This is is one of my `if` statements:

```
if input == "open"
  if data[1] != nil
    puts "The open of your stock is: " +  data[1]
  else
    puts "Sorry, but that value wasn't recorded"
  end
end
```

Let me know of you need the rest of the program.

Comment: If there's an error at `lookup.rb:75`, post `lookup.rb:75` and as much surrounding code as possible please. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like

```
if data && data[1] != nil
```

which will check if `data` exists before it tries to access the `data[1]` element

Answer (score 0):

Without the rest of the code, this just looks like you're using `data` when it's nil.  If this is the case, just don't do that.

Something like this may help:

```
if input == "open" && !data.nil?
    if data[1] != nil
        puts "The open of your stock is: " +  data[1]
    else
        puts "Sorry, but that value wasn't recorded"
    end
end
```

But there's likely a better solution if we had your code to look at.

Comment: Testing for `nil` isn't necessary as long as `data` can never be `false`. That reduces the code: `if input == "open" && !data.nil?` to `if (input == "open") && data`, and `if data[1] != nil` to `if data[1]`